# Auto submit function after X characters

Tags: javascript, html

currently i have a function in my code where it takes input from a barcode scanner and when pressed it will submit the data to another html, currently iam finding ways to make it so it auto submits once it has 9 characters.

```
    <div class="section" id="instruction-3">
  
            <span>
                <input type="text" id="IC-input" name="IC" onclick="openKeyboard()" maxlength="9" placeholder="Enter your Number" required maxlength="9">
                <label><button type="button" id="theButton" onclick="theButtonIsPressed()">Submit</button></label>
            </span>
        </div>
```

and what happens when the button is pressed

```
        function theButtonIsPressed(){
        NRIC = '{"NRIC":"123456789"}';
        document.getElementById("IC-input").value = "";
        doWork(NRIC)
```

Does anyone have a solution to make it so the button is clicked automatically and will make it so the maxlength is at 9 as the one in my code cant seem to work.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  function openKeyboard(value){
    console.log(value.length);
    button = document.getElementById("theButton");
    if(value.length == 9){
          console.log('form is ready to submit');
           button.click();
        }  
    }
    
     function theButtonIsPressed(){
                console.log('button clicked');
                NRIC = '{"NRIC":"T0204247E"}';
        document.getElementById("IC-input").value = "";
        //doWork(NRIC)
        }
```

```html
<div class="section" id="instruction-3">
  <span>
    <input type="text" id="IC-input" name="IC" onkeyup="openKeyboard(this.value)" placeholder="Enter your Number" required maxlength="9">
    <label><button type="button" id="theButton" onclick="theButtonIsPressed()">Submit</button></label>
  </span>
</div>
```

you can use `onkeyup` event to track the length of the input value, if it's satisfied then your button will click automatic.

Comment: Ah thank you so much! i did not expect to receive a working answer so soon! After trying your solution it worked perfectly! thank you so much!

Comment: a pleasure to help, happy coding champ:-)

Answer (score 0):

```
const input = document.getElementById("IC-input");

input.addEventListener('change', handleValueChange);

function handleValueChange(e) {
  if (e.target.value.length >= 9) {
    // input reached length 9
    const value = e.target.value;
    const NRIC = { NRIC: value};
    document.getElementById("IC-input").value = "";
    doWork(NRIC)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Credits to @CodeBug, it works fine!

Submit

```
  function openKeyboard(value){
console.log(value.length);
button = document.getElementById("theButton");
if(value.length == 9){
      console.log('form is ready to submit');
       button.click();
    }  
}

 function theButtonIsPressed(){
            console.log('button clicked');
            NRIC = '{"NRIC":"T0204247E"}';
    document.getElementById("IC-input").value = "";
    //doWork(NRIC)
    }
```